# AndroidTV in portrait orientation

Tags: android, android-tv, landscape-portrait, android-fullscreen

I am working on an AndroidTV application that should be compatible to work as a kiosk app. That means that some users may want to use it **with the screen in vertical**.

I tried to perform an orientation change when pressing a button but it is not working as I expected (the screen orientation changes but the view is compressed and does not fulfill the whole screen of the TV). I tested the same code with mobile/tablet and it worked fine.

Here is my code:

```
    private var toggle: Boolean = false

    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean =
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT -> {
                toggleOrientation()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
        }

    private fun toggleOrientation() {
        requestedOrientation = if (toogle) {
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        } else {
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }
        toogle = !toogle
    }
```

And the result on emulator AndroidTV (720) API 29 when changing to portrait is:
[image]

How can I see my app fit the full screen on portrait mode for an AndroidTV?

Comment: Are you sure the kiosks are running Android TV and not Android mobile? Android TV is heavily designed around landscape (including the emulator) and is expected to not work well in portrait.

Comment: I know that it's strange but they are basically using a television in vertical on storefront (without interactions) from some bussiness related to "attract/capture users". And yes, they are using AndroidTVs for that purpose.
Anyway, thanks for the information, I think i will perform rotation programatically and recompute View's size after invalidating layout.

Comment: can you please post your solution to "perform rotation programmatically" ?